# Why "static" keyword needs to be in Program Class in C#?

Tags: c#, static

I am not sure why when I don't use "static", the function has error:

```
"An object reference is required for non-static field,method, or property.Dos2Unix(string)"
```

The code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = @"\D:\temp\test.xls";
        Dos2Unix(f);
    }
    private void Dos2Unix(string fileName)
    {
       const byte CR = 0x0D;
       const byte LF = 0x0A;
       byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
       using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
       {
           BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
           int position = 0;
           int index = 0;
           do
           {
             index = Array.IndexOf<byte>(data, CR, position);
             if ((index >= 0) && (data[index + 1] == LF))
             {
               // Write before the CR
               bw.Write(data, position, index - position);
               // from LF
               position = index + 1;
             }
           }
                while (index > 0);
                bw.Write(data, position, data.Length - position);
                fileStream.SetLength(fileStream.Position);
            }
    }
 }
}
```

When I use the keyword "static", there is no error.

I am not sure what error I am making. Need some help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling non-static method `this` parameter implictly passed into the method

```
  private void Dos2Unix(string fileName) {
    ...
    var sample = this.GetType(); // <- possible call
    ...
  }
```

Static method can't provide such parameter (`this`) and so you have an error.
In your case you don't want `Program` class instance within `Dos2Unix` method, so make it static:

```
  class Program 
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = @"\D:\temp\test.xls";
        Dos2Unix(f);
    } 

    // Please, note "static"
    private static void Dos2Unix(string fileName) 
    {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Technically, you dont't want `Program` class instances at all, and so declare the *entire class* as `static`:

```
   // class is static
   static class Program 
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var f = @"\D:\temp\test.xls";
        Dos2Unix(f);
      } 

      // all methods are static
      private static void Dos2Unix(string fileName) 
      {
       ...
      }
   }
```

Comment: +1 for recognising that OP does not require an **instance at all** compared to the alternate answers here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not call non static method from static method directly, as Main method of Program class is static you can only call static method of program class from this method.

To call a non static method from Main method you can make object of program class and call non static method on this object.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var f = @"\D:\temp\test.xls";
    Program p = new Program();
    p.Dos2Unix(f);
}
```

There is a reason why static method can not call non-static methods as the static method are not tied to instance of that class on the other hand the non-static method is tied to instance (can access the non-static data members). Think a static method calling a non-static method that is accessing instance members that actually does not exist for class, because the static method is called upon class not instance. You can read further in this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284088/why-static-methods-cant-call-non-static-methods-directly).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a non-static method from the static method `Main`, you'll have to create a new object of type `Program`:

```
new Program().Dos2Unix(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an instance of your class.
This should work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        var f = @"\D:\temp\test.xls";
        p.Dos2Unix(f);
    }
    private void Dos2Unix(string fileName)
    {
       const byte CR = 0x0D;
       const byte LF = 0x0A;
       byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
       using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
       {
           BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
           int position = 0;
           int index = 0;
           do
           {
             index = Array.IndexOf<byte>(data, CR, position);
             if ((index >= 0) && (data[index + 1] == LF))
             {
               // Write before the CR
               bw.Write(data, position, index - position);
               // from LF
               position = index + 1;
             }
           }
                while (index > 0);
                bw.Write(data, position, data.Length - position);
                fileStream.SetLength(fileStream.Position);
            }
    }
 }
}
```

So basically you only need to add:

```
Program p = new Program();
```

and call your method like:

```
p.Dos2Unix("....");
```

That's because you can't access a non-static method inside a static method (you can't also use this by the way).